# jQuery UI animation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have built a slider with jQueryUI through much effort (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481602/jquery-slider-performing-unexpectedly/)) but I have the slight issue of the `<ul>` tag no longer sliding with animation like it used to? I want to use the handle and watch the `<ul>` slide smoothly, but no code I can think of is making it work? Any ideas? Test sample of page [here](http://dronnoc.com/temp/aiki_books/slider-fail/slider.html).

All I would really love is for the `<ul>` to move smoothly when I move the handle or click on the sliders path.

Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the stop method before the animation and replace the slide function with the animation too.

```
$('.handle', container).slider({
    ...
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(".pics").stop().animate({"left" : ui.value * -1}, 500);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".pics").stop().animate({"left" : ui.value * -1}, 500);
    }
});
```

Also see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9srdk/) where I moved the callbacks to one function.

Comment: My friend, you're a gentleman and a scholar! Great work, thank you very much :)